# Laravel Date to German Monthnames?

Tags: laravel

I have laravel and have this function to print the date when the user registered on our site

```
{{ __("Member Since :time",["time"=> date("M Y",strtotime($user->created_at))]) }}
```

But it gives "Oct" (English). But i want this in German. But how can i make this in frontend?

Thats the code in the frontend file

```
<p class="profile-since">{{ __("Member Since :time",["time"=> date("M Y",strtotime($user->created_at))]) }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setlocale()`

https://www.php.net/setlocale

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge');
```

If you set this before you echo your code it should change to the locale

Or if you use carbon you can change it globally in  `config/app.php`

```
'locale' => 'id'
```

Comment: @rchatbum doesnt work when i set this before the code that implement it with laravel {{ }} function. Please look my code at the top, thats the "echo" but where did i add that there?